# Select into a view

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, sql-view

I have a simple CTE `x` and I wish to select its contents into a view.  Can you select into a view using the same type of syntax that you can for a table? i.e.

```
SELECT * 
INTO newTable
FROM OldTable
```

Can new views be created dynamically like this?

Comment: @codingbiz i have no idea how to try it out. since `select * 
into Paraplegia view
from x` didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [automatically create views for a bunch of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237740/automatically-create-views-for-a-bunch-of-tables)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create view myView
AS
with x
as
(select 1 as num)
select * from x
```